# What's wrong with this Python folder structure?

Tags: python-3.x, directory-structure

I thought I understood Python 3's module model, but perhaps not.

I have a tree like:

```
root
\-- pmlr
    \-- __init__.py * empty
    \-- pmlr.py     * full of definitions
```

When I'm in `root`, and I run from the Python3 shell `import pmlr`, `pmlr` only has these attributes (the default package `__dict__`):

```
pmlr.__cached__         pmlr.__dir__(           pmlr.__format__(        pmlr.__hash__(          pmlr.__lt__(            pmlr.__package__        pmlr.__repr__(          pmlr.__str__(
pmlr.__class__(         pmlr.__doc__            pmlr.__ge__(            pmlr.__init__(          pmlr.__name__           pmlr.__path__           pmlr.__setattr__(       pmlr.__subclasshook__(
pmlr.__delattr__(       pmlr.__eq__(            pmlr.__getattribute__(  pmlr.__le__(            pmlr.__ne__(            pmlr.__reduce__(        pmlr.__sizeof__(        
pmlr.__dict__           pmlr.__file__           pmlr.__gt__(            pmlr.__loader__         pmlr.__new__(           pmlr.__reduce_ex__(     pmlr.__spec__
```

That means `python` thinks `pmlr` is a *package*, but it can't find any of its attributes.

If I `cd pmlr` and *then* import it, all of the module's attributes are shown. If I `import pmlr.pmlr` from `root`, all of the module's attributes are shown.

How can I make my module importable from the root directory as its folder (`pmlr`), instead of as `pmlr.pmlr`? I thought `__init__.py` is what accomplished this.

Comment: In `__init__.py` use `from .pmlr import *`.

Comment: @Rogalski post that as an answer, thank you -- I didn't think to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rogalski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2912340/rogalski) explained it in the comments:

> In `__init__.py` use `from pmlr import *`.